# Support Option-Return for inserting new lines in Super User chat

Tags: bug, chat, javascript

On Mac OS X, pressing `Option-Return` inserts newlines in text input fields instead of e.g. submitting a form. This is a system-wide convention (Cocoa's `insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor:`).

Very few programs, like the Safari web browser, require focus on an input field that doesn't handle `Return` itself for the form to submit. For these (`<textarea>`, essentially), **both** pressing `Return` *and* `Option-Return` work for inserting a line break.

---

Super User Chat only supports entering multiple lines by pressing `Shift-Enter`. In all other cases, it hijacks the `Return` key-down event and submits. This is the relevant piece of code, as far as I can tell:

```
function(a) {
    var b = !1;
    ka = ka && (38 == a.which || 40 == a.which);
    switch (a.which) {
    case 13:
        !a.shiftKey && !e && (ya(), b = !0);
        break;
        [lines skipped...]
    }
    b && a.preventDefault()
}
```

From what I can tell, `ya()` is the submit function call.

**Please also allow use of `Option-Return` for inserting newlines, consistent with OS X platform standards.** AFAICT, this will have no adverse effects on other functionality.

```
!a.shiftKey && !a.altKey && !e && (ya(), b = !0);
```

---

I classify this issue as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), since the implementation of the submit button acts different from system-wide basic text editing behavior for all users of OS X used to platform conventions. `Opt-Enter` *never* leaves the field editor or submits, *except in SE chat*.

True, it's a web application and platform independent etc., but how basic must expected functionality be before *different* becomes *wrong*?